# Restrict change in value of valueNotifier.value

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check in my app anywhere if the user is an admin or not. For that, I am first fetching the admins list from the server and set a global file that contains `ValueNotifier<bool> admin` to notify if we have set or change the value of admin after fetching the admin list. But problem is that `admin.value` setter will also be accessible to all files to set its value, but I want to restrict it such that the value of `admin` can only be changed in Networks class or Network files or any other specific files, while I want to listen on its changes anywhere possible. Can anyone help me?

Comment: publish your `ValueNotifier` as `ValueListenable<bool>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your `ValueNotifier` a private instance so it will only be accessible and editable in its current class then make a public getter for its listenable value which you will be able to call from outside.

**Example**

```dart
class Network{
   // private variable only accessible inside the class
   final ValueNotifier<bool> _isAdminNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

   // public getter accessible outside
   ValueListenable<bool> get isAdmin => _isAdminNotifier;
}
```

Try the full example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/031084665ea6ae167744988911c53fe9).

Answer (score 0):

Ok Got it, I can create a `ValueListenable<bool>` getter on `ValueNotifier<bool> admin`.